# writing a .exe file to write text file to client-side in php

Tags: php, web-services, phpmyadmin, client-server, client-side

I would like to write a file to the client-side in php.

The problem with php is that it will only write in the server-side.

I need help because i dont know how to do it.

### What I have:

Whenever a client clicks a link to a page it will run the script that will write to a text file which contains a query results from a database known as a flatfile. But it is not possible for client-side in php.

### What I need:

Whenever a client click the link, it will download a .exe file.
In the .exe is the php script that will write a file to the client's hdd.
After the .exe file is downloaded, it will automatically run and create the file on the path specified.

Please, I need help to finish my education.

Comment: `After the .exe file is downloaded, it will automatically run` Generally speaking, you can't auto-run an .exe, much less force the client to download it.  It'd be a huge security hole.  If any browsers allow it, users would have to specifically whitelist your site to allow it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create the file on the server side and serve it via a URL? The user can then save it to their computer. If you tried to send an EXE file, the user would have to save that, anyway, and they'd be much less likely to actually want to do it!

Comment: the text file that is to be written in the client hdd consists of activity files which was sessioned and scheduled... i need it to the client-side to be loaded in a flash which the user must perform. if input in the server... different users have different activities to perform thus, there will be conflict since there could be many scheduled activities to be performed by the user.